# Creation of 161.b file

Tags: ios, objective-c, gracenote

How is the `161.b` file in Gracenotes example project `GN_Music_SDK_iOS` project created and how exactly is it used?

The application is running fine after deleting the file. It does not get recreated.

How is such a cache file supposed to look like before its first usage? Simply an empty file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a seed file with fingerprints and results supplied by Gracenote. It is distributed with the SDK, and does not get mutated during the lifecycle of the application.